# Why does my desktop broadcast WORGROUP name queries over DNS and NETBIOS (NBNS)?

Tags: networking, security, dns, system, workgroup

I have a fresh and up-to-date installation of xenial desktop (16.04.03).
It is broadcasting NBNS and DNS name requests, looking for WORKGROUP peers, despite the fact that Samba is not installed.
This trafic is not supposed to exist on my network. It is polluting my logs and triggering alerts. For security reasons I want to completely turn it off.
Why does my desktop generate this undesired network trafic? 
Which process is responsible for this behaviour?
How can I completely disable it?
Thanks in advance for any help.